# Defining many-to-many connection defining ICollection<> only in one class

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-standard

I have an .NET application with the validation logic outsourced to a .NET Core API. There are some models and logics that both of them use and I want them to use the same classes from a (.net standard) Nuget package. The main problem that I'm using **Entity Framework code-first**, and some of the common models are in database too but i don't want to include f.e. **ApplicationUser** in the nuget package.
There is a model with a many-to-many connection to **ApplicationUser** and I don't want to define the **ICollection** in it.

So my "local" class looks something like this:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    ....

    public ICollection<Institute> Institutes { get; set; }

    ....
}
```

And my "remote" class looks like this:

```
public class Institute
{
    ....

    public ICollection<ApplicationUser> Users { get; set; }

    ....
}
```

But I don't want Institute to have this `public ICollection<ApplicationUser> Users { get; set; }` but I want the **EF** to map the many-to-many connection. If I delete it from the **Institute** class the next migration will delete the whole ApplicationUserInstitute connection table.

I have thought of some kind of inheritance solution but I think future development would be pain in the ass with it. Every possible solution is welcomed.

Comment: You could manually create a new class to define the `ApplicationUserInstitute` mapping table and thereafter get rid of the navigational properties from the original classes/tables

Comment: Why don't you want that navigation property?  They make doing Linq queries easier.

Comment: @juharr Yes it makes it easier but if i do that way there should be a reference to the ApplicationUser class, or a defined ApplicationUser with a reference to IdentityUser so it's not really the right way because I want this project to be as independent as it can be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need explicitly override `OnModelCreating()` in your context and specify Many-to-Many relation there:

```
        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

            modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
            .HasMany(s => s.Institues)
            .WithMany()
            .Map(cs =>
            {
                cs.MapLeftKey("UserRefId");
                cs.MapRightKey("InstituteRefId");
                cs.ToTable("UserInsitute");
            });
        }
```

I used entities from [this article](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-many-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx) to generate schema. The only difference is that I removed         `public virtual ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; }` from `Course`.

[image]